# Signalr WebSockets not working on Windows server 2012 R2 + IIS 8.5 with enabled websocket protocol, But works on local development machine (Win 10)

Tags: windows, websocket, server, signalr

Signalr WebSockets not working on Windows server 2012 R2 + IIS 8.5 with enabled websocket protocol, But works on local development machine (Win 10).

Both set-up as per:
https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/websocket

Server (Websockets not working)
-Windows 2012 R2 Standard
-IIS 8.5 
-Websockets enabled 
-Client Chrome version 58 64bit (Running locally on server just like dev machine - to eliminate load balancer, or network issue)
Signal returns TryWebSockets:false (SSE, longpolling and Forever Frame do work)

Local Development Machine (WebSockets are working)
-Windows 10
-IIS 10.0.10586.0
-Client Chrome version 58 64bit
Signal returns TryWebSockets:true

Web.config has:

```
<system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"...
```

and

```
<compilation defaultLanguage="c#" debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2">
```

Grasping at straws:

1. Adding `<appSettings><add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>`
   ~No change Local works / server did not
2. re-install the signalr packages
   ~No change Local works / server did not (referenced Form:
   [SignalR won't use Websocket protocol even though I have the protocol installed in windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12924607/signalr-wont-use-websocket-protocol-even-though-i-have-the-protocol-installed-i))
3. Tried uppgrading to Signalr 2.2.2 form 2.2.1
   ~No change Local works / server did not
4. Server restarts
   ~No change Local works / server did not
5. Testing change to `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.2"...`
   ~No change Local works / server did not
6. Client side explicitly set to use websockets

   $.connection.hub.start({ transport: 'webSockets' }, function () {
                   console.log('connection started WebSockets!');
               }).done(function ()

~No change Local works / server did not

Checked Assemblies 
https://forums.asp.net/p/1872743/5263876.aspx

Comment: Create the hello world from here to ensure it was not some kind of conflict: http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/getting-started-with-signalr/

Comment: Still no luck, works on newer windows 2012 R2 servers.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out to be missing a line in the applicationhost.config, needed to be updated to include:

`<add name="WebSocketModule" lockItem="true" />`