# SignalR cannot read property client of undefined for MS Server 2012 R2

Tags: c#, signalr-hub, signalr.client

It is ok with MS Server 2012, but in MS Server 2012 R2 it shows error below.

Thanks in advance for the help.

[In the below image you can see the error I'm receiving.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXbB8.png)

Comment: We need more information. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878470/signalr-websockets-not-working-on-windows-server-2012-r2-iis-8-5-with-enabled) SO question and update your question.

Comment: Provide your client and server code